# What is the difference? "Are you watching" vs "Have you been watching"

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense

What is the difference between these sentences?

> **Have you been watching** TV for the last four hours? Turn it off and get
>   some exercise?
>
> **Are you watching** TV for the last four hours? Turn it off and get some
>   exercise?

Comment: I would suggest the second one is not grammatically correct. "Are you watching" (present tense) doesn't match with "for the last four hours" (past action, even though you're still doing it now).